# T-SQL INSERT multiple child records in one statement

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

So, you can INSERT multiple rows at once with syntax such as:

```
INSERT INTO Table
SELECT Field1,
       Expression2
  FROM DataSource
```

The common pattern for inserting a child record for a row might be syntax such as:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Field1, Field2)
  VALUES (Expression1, Expression2)

UPDATE Table1
  SET Table2ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  WHERE Table1ID = @ParentID
```

Is there any way to merge these two concepts, rapidly inserting a range of child records where the parent ID for each one is known (and not all the same), and the child's ID is assigned by an `IDENTITY` column, and where the parent record refers to the child record?

Here's a sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 -- Child table
(
  Table2ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Field1 ...,
  Field2 ...,
)

CREATE TABLE Table1 -- Parent Table
(
  Table1ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  FieldA ...,
  FieldB ...,
  Table2ID INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table2 (Table2ID)
)
```

(The astute reader may notice that this is a one-to-(zero or one) relationship. This suggests simply using `Table1`'s key as the key for `Table2` as well. This, unfortunately, doesn't work here. These tables are part of a greater schema, in which `Table2` can have parents in multiple other tables, and also can contain records which stand alone.)

My input is a table variable `@IDs` with a list of `Table1ID`s. A subset of the `Table1` records identified by this input have `NULL Table2ID` values. My objective is to create a new `Table2` record for each one of these, and simultaneously update the `Table1` records to point at their new children.

I have tried every combination of CTEs and `OUTPUT` clause I could think and can't find a way to insert the `Table1ID` alongside each new `INSERTED.Table2ID`. The `OUTPUT` clause can't reference columns that aren't part of the target table of the `INSERT` statement.

Does not work:

```
WITH NewData (Table1ID, Field1, Field2)
AS
(
  SELECT Table1ID,
         Expression1,
         Expression2
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN @IDs AS IDs
      ON Table1.Table1ID = IDs.Value
    WHERE Table2ID IS NULL
)
INSERT INTO Table2 (Field1, Field2)
  OUTPUT INSERTED.Table2ID, NewData.Table1ID -- Error here
  VALUES (NewData.Field1, NewData.Field2)
```

The only ways I can think of to do this are:

1. Update the schema for `Table2` to contain a `Table1ID`. With this, the `INSERT` statement could take the `Table1ID` from the `SELECT` statement generating `Table2` fields based on `Table1` parent records with no children and put it into the actual inserted data. A subsequent statement could then invert the direction of the reference and populate the `Table2ID` values in `Table1`.
2. Use a cursor on the `@IDs` input sequence, and do a separate single-row `INSERT` statement for each new `Table2` record. The corresponding `Table1` record could then be immediately `UPDATE`d with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

However, the first option requires a permanent change to the schema for storing temporary data in this operation, and the second option requires manually iterating through the records, negating the performance benefits of preparing a batch of rows to be inserted in a single statement to the database engine.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a little odd - it refers in several places to a parent table having 'children', however with the schema you describe, Table1 (the parent) can only ever have a single Table2 child at any one time - this is a one-to-one relationship.

You have in fact noticed this yourself, where it is much easier to insert multiple Table2 entries with a parent Table1 id (because this works).

If what you do want is a one-to-one relationship, then a more common schema might be:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 -- Parent Table
(
  Table1ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  FieldA ...,
  FieldB ...
)

CREATE TABLE Table2 -- Child table
(
  Table1ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Field1 ...,
  Field2 ...,
)

ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1 FOREIGN KEY (Table1ID)
REFERENCES Table1 (Table1ID)
GO
```

In this case, the primary key in the child is not generated, but instead matches the PK in the parent table.

Comment: That is true. I overlooked an aspect of this schema. `Table2` is a child of more than one other table, and can also contain records that don't have an external parent. I'll try to find a logical place to edit that into the question. Thanks!